# android development with scala

Tags: android, scala, command-line

The first thing described in the howto (http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Developing_for_Android) is this:

Step 1:  Create the ant files for your project:

```
 cd <project dir>
 android update project --target 1 --path .
```

which yields 'command not found'. I'm in the 'workspace/name_of_my_app/' folder.

How do I get to have the 'android' command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup the environmental variables for andriod sdk properly.  Here is documentation for the andriod command you are trying to execute:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/othertools.html#android

Comment: Hm.

I wrote:

javac -version

and was told i had to install openjdk-6-jdk, since sun-java6-jdk did not have javac. So I did.

After that, the android command magically just worked. I'm not much less confused than before.

Comment: I had this problem. I just had to specify the full path to the tools folder within the android sdk and the command worked fine.